# HTML video can't read local video file containing cyrillic symbols. How can i solve this?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, url, html5-video

I try to play local video file in html video tag, I use open dialog to choose file and get file's path. Then I put this path in src

```
export default function VideoContainer() {
  const { videoUrl } = useTypeSelector(state => state.video);
  console.log(videoUrl);

  return (
    <div className='VideoContainer'>
      {videoUrl !== '' && (
        <video className='VideoContainer__video' controls>
          <source src={`custom-protocol://${videoUrl}`} type={`video/mp4`} />
        </video>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For cyrillic files it doesn't work. [error with cyrillic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qA4G.png)
How can I fix this?

I use Electron.js, React.js, Redux.

This what i've tried:

```
export default function VideoContainer() {
  const { videoUrl } = useTypeSelector(state => state.video);
  const newStr = decodeURI(videoUrl);
  console.log(newStr);

  return (
    <div className='VideoContainer'>
      {videoUrl !== '' && (
        <video className='VideoContainer__video' controls>
          <source src={`custom-protocol://${newStr}`} type={`video/mp4`} />
        </video>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

but this same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDXAl.png).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure to take the [tour] and read [ask] as it can help you make posts that produce favorable results for both you and the community. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by [decoding the URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) where you pass your videoURL string as function input.

In Javascript, you can do it like example below (research for same code result via: React / Electron / Redux)...

```
videoURL = ...some_Cyrillic_text_encoding_with_%_sign...

//# update the string with decoded version of itself
videoURL = decodeURI( videoURL ); //eg: gives шеллы as new URL
```

You can see it solves the same problem of text encoding shown in your picture:

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but something turns back my string in encodeURI when i put decodeURI(videoURL) in src video. Automatically